# Datatable column filtering not working server side

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have already done server side processing  in datatable.
Now i want to make individual column filtering server side processing as well.

I have tried.

```
 $('#example thead th').each(function () {
     var title = $(this).text();
     $(this).html(title+' <input type="text" class="col-search-input" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'lfBrtip',
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "ajax":{
            "url":"{{route('homeajax')}}",
            "dataType": "json",
            "type": "POST",
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"name"},
            {"data":"Position"},
            {"data":"office"},
            {"data":"age"},
            {"data":"start_date"},
            {"data":"salary"},
        ],
        initComplete: function(){
            this.api().columns().every(function(){
                $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (table.search() !== this.value) {
                        table.search(this.value,true).draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        paginate: true,   
    });
```

It works for only one column but when i try to search from another field it doesn't work.

It shows all the data when i try to input from another column,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on server side query which you used for data fetching. If joins in your query then you need to pass column name like below code.

```
"columns":[
        {"data":"name"},
        {"data":"tbl.Position"}, //tbl is join table alias.
        {"data":"office"},
        {"data":"age"},
        {"data":"start_date"},
        {"data":"salary"},
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it disrupts your design a little but are you able to let DataTables create the search inputs? That way it can set the event listener to search only that column. I use a variation of the code from this link:

http://live.datatables.net/tobekuxu/1/edit

Another thing to look at (perhaps try this first) is I think you are searching the whole table when you want to be searching only that column. Try something like this inside your columns().every() function:

```
this.api().columns().every(function(){
    let column = this;
    $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
        if (column.search() !== this.value) {
            column.search(this.value,true).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this ajax code will help for you. [aoColumns](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)
if you need to enable filter only name,Position and start_date(Custom filter)

```
 "aoColumns": [
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": false }
    ]
```